# What's the difference between the following codes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, floating-point, typeerror

*Python*

**Code - 1**

```
hrs = input("Enter Hours:")
rate = input("Enter Rate:")
pay = float(hrs * rate)
    print("Pay:", pay)
```

**Code - 2**

```
 hrs = input("Enter Hours:")
 rate = input("Enter Rate:")
 pay = float(hrs) * float(rate)
    print("Pay:", pay)
```

While executing the Code - 1 I'm getting the following error -
 "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' on line 5" but the Code - 2 is completely fine and running. I just want to know that is there really any difference between these 2 codes? If yes, then what is it? (I'm a novice who just started with programming )

Comment: "input" always returns a string and evaluation of expressions (like the one to the right of = in third lines) follows the usual order similar to arithmetic (here: from inside parentheses to outside).

Comment: function `input` returns a string.  So in code 1 it would be like saying `float("45.25" * "25.81")` thus asking to multiply two strings and convert the result to a float.

Answer (score 2):

This code `float(hrs * rate)` cannot work because `hrs` and `rate` are both strings. What would you expect to be the result of `"hello" * "world"`?

When you do `float(hrs) * float(rate)` on the other hand, you are multiplying the result of two calls to `float` - in other words, you are multiplying two floats.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code, you multiply 2 variables first, then convert it to `float`, but if one of them is `str` (or both in this case), then there will be an error.

In the second code, you convert each of them to `float` before multiplying, that's why there is no error at all